# How to implement a C# delegate containing an in-struct parameter in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Given the following delegate definition in C#:

```
struct Dummy {}
delegate int ReceiveDummy(in Dummy dummy);
```

How can I assign a a VB.Net sub to the ReceiveDummy type? Both the following function definitions fail with error BC30657: "has a return type that is not supported or parameter types that are not supported".

```
Shared Function MyReceiveDummy(ByVal dummy As Dummy) As Integer
Shared Function MyReceiveDummy(ByRef dummy As Dummy) As Integer
Dim receive As ReceiveDummy = New ReceiveDummy(AddressOf MyReceiveDummy)
```

Is there a VB.NET equivalent to C#'s "in" keyword?

Comment: The direct match would be something like `Const ByRef` or `ReadOnly ByRef`, so it avoids needing to copy or duplicate the data while still ensuring the original is not changed: the best of both worlds from both performance and safety standpoints. I expect you understand that, because you knew enough to use `in` in the first place on the C# side. Unfortunately, I don't think VB.Net has anything like this.

Comment: That's too bad. Am I correct to think then, that the given delegate definition just plainly *cannot* be implemented in VB? Perhaps using some function-pointer-casting like tricks? I always thought c#'s in/out/ref are all just "ref" under the hood, with some additional compiler checks on the c# side for in/out.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn could you make an answer out of your comment so I can accept it?

Comment: There's still hope someone chimes in and contradicts me on this.

Comment: I'll wait a bit, then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In you vb.net code, can you at least refer to the **type** `ReceiveDummy`, e.g. does `GetType(ReceiveDummy)` compile in vb.net?  Or can you declare a function that returns `ReceiveDummy` but just throws an exception and doesn't return anything?

Comment: @madreflection thanks for the clarification. That raises another question though, I also tried "[InAttribute] ByRef dummy as Dummy", but no luck. Does the VB compiler not process that attribute?

Comment: @dbc absolutely. I can declare variables of ReceiveDummy, pass objects of that type around, etc etc. I just can't cook up a VB.Net function which matches the signature. In case you're interested, this is the reason i asked in the first place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724264/recording-audio-using-xtaudio-in-vb-net.

Comment: OK, then I have a **super hacky** way to do this.  Want it?

Comment: @dbc I already recommended the person on the topic I just mentioned, to just write a small bit of c# wrapper code, which seems like the safe course of action. But, just for fun, I'd like to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **extremely hacky**, but it turns out to be possible (in .NET 7) to use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=net-7.0) to create a delegate of a type with an `in` parameter from a static method whose signature actually accepts a `ref` parameter.

E.g. if I create (in C#):

```cs
struct Dummy {}
delegate int ReceiveDummy(in Dummy dummy);

static class DummyActions
{
    //https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#metadata-representation-of-in-parameters
    static int ActuallyReceiveDummy(ref Dummy dummy)
    {
        return dummy.GetHashCode();
    }
    
    public static ReceiveDummy CreateReceiveDummy()
    {
        return (ReceiveDummy)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ReceiveDummy), 
                                    typeof(DummyActions).GetMethod(nameof(DummyActions.ActuallyReceiveDummy), 
                                                                   BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
    }
}
```

I can do:

```
var receiveMethod = DummyActions.CreateReceiveDummy();
Console.WriteLine(receiveMethod(new Dummy()));
```

An it works!  Demo #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zjB1UO).

Translating to VB.NET, I get the following:

```vb
Friend Class DummyActions
    ' https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#metadata-representation-of-in-parameters
    Private Shared Function ActuallyReceiveDummy(ByRef dummy As Dummy) As Integer
        ' Do whatever you want here but don't modify dummy!
        Return dummy.GetHashCode() 
    End Function

    Public Shared Function CreateReceiveDummy() As ReceiveDummy
        Return CType([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(ReceiveDummy), 
            GetType(DummyActions).GetMethod(NameOf(DummyActions.ActuallyReceiveDummy), 
                BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)), ReceiveDummy)
    End Function
End Class
```

Which makes the following possible in VB.NET:

```vb
Dim receiveMethod = DummyActions.CreateReceiveDummy()
Console.WriteLine(receiveMethod(New Dummy()))
```

Mockup fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D56O9I)

Notes:

- According to the [design documents for `in` in C# 7.2](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#metadata-representation-of-in-parameters)

  > When `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute` is applied to a byref parameter, it means that the parameter is an `in` parameter.
  >
  > In addition, if the method is abstract or virtual, then the signature of such parameters (and only such parameters) must have `modreq[System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute]`.
  >
  > Motivation: this is done to ensure that in a case of method overriding/implementing the in parameters match.
  >
  > Same requirements apply to `Invoke` methods in delegates.
  >
  > Motivation: this is to ensure that existing compilers cannot simply ignore `readonly` when creating or assigning delegates.

  It turns out that **in C#** the compiler will not allow you to manually apply `IsReadOnlyAttribute`, if you try you will get a compiler error *Do not use 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute'. This is reserved for compiler usage.* (demo #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lNT4CT)).  But the VB.NET compiler makes no such restriction, so if you want to "future-proof" your method against some possible future version of `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` that checks for this attribute, you could add it manually:

  ```vb
  ' https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#metadata-representation-of-in-parameters
  Private Shared Function ActuallyReceiveDummy(<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute()> ByRef dummy As Dummy) As Integer
      ' Do whatever you want here but don't modify dummy!
      Return dummy.GetHashCode() 
  End Function
  ```

  The VB.NET compiler does not seem to know about or account for this attribute in any way.

  Demo #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQMRHu).
- This whole idea does an end-run around the principle that the framework prevents `in` parameters from being modified, and so is super hacky.  Thus you need to manually take care not to modify your `ByRef dummy as Dummy` argument in any way.

**As an alternative**,  If you are willing to write a little bit of C# code, then as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76744987/3744182) by [Sjoerd van Kreel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227563/sjoerd-van-kreel) to *[Recording Audio using XtAudio in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76724264/3744182)*, you could write an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) extension method in C# that creates a `ReceiveDummy` delegate from a delegate taking `Dummy` by value:

```
public delegate int ReceiveDummyByValue(Dummy dummy);

public static class DummyActions
{
    public static ReceiveDummy AsReceiveByReference(this ReceiveDummyByValue func) => (in Dummy d) => func(d);
}
```

Then in your main VB.NET code, use it e.g. as follows:

```vb
Private Shared Function ActuallyReceiveDummy(ByVal d As Dummy) As Integer
    ' Return whatever is required for dummy
    Return d.GetHashCode()
End Function

Public Shared Function CreateReceiveDummy() As ReceiveDummy
    Return (New ReceiveDummyByValue(AddressOf ActuallyReceiveDummy)).AsReceiveByReference()
End Function
```

Comment: You might also be able to do something with `System.Linq.Expressions` and `MakeByRefType()`.  See e.g. [Supporting "out / ref" parameters in expressions with conversion to "object"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474754) or [Is it possible to have an out ParameterExpression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12322641).

Comment: well that's what I get for asking for function-pointer-casting tricks I guess :) This is exactly what I asked for though, so I'm going to accept the answer. I will leave my original answer to the other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724264/recording-audio-using-xtaudio-in-vb-net "as is", just write a c# wrapper. It'd be good if you could just put a small note on top of your answer, that writing a wrapper in c# is probably the way to go.

Comment: @SjoerdvanKreel - added (though at the bottom, as an alternative).